# Manage exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot

I developed an application spring boot. I wand to manage exceptions and not send error 500 to the client.

I want to do something like that:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/testRest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Person tst(HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            return ldapService.getUserByPrimaryKey("tst@ts.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return (Person) "{\"ERROR\": \" + e.getMessage() +\"}";   // This not work
        }
    }
```

Would you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> return (Person) "{\"ERROR\": \" + e.getMessage() +\"}";   // This not work

This doesn't work because you're trying to cast `String` object to a `Person` type. It shouldn't even compile I believe.

There are 2 ways of how to resolve this:

- return `Person` object and because you're using `@ResponseBody` it will be serialized to a JSON
- if you want to manually return a JSON response, then you should return `String` instead of `Person` and also properly set a `Content-Type` header (by using `@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json"` or `response.setContentType("application/json")`)

I'd also suggest to read [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) article to find more ways of handling exceptons in Spring MVC.

---

Updated:

in such a simple case, you can use a `Map` with a single field:

```
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> tst(HttpServletResponse response) {
   ...
   return Collections.singletonMap("ERROR": e.getMessage());
```

Comment: What I want is when is ok return the Person object and when it is not ok for example an error 500 I will return a JSOn like that {"error": "the exception details"}

Comment: You should mention that in the description. In this case you have to use something like `@AdviceController` (see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes) because it's impossible to return objects with a different types from the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ControllerAdvice, I explain :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionsHandlerController{

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  @ResponseBody Person handleException(){
   //do what you want 
  }
}
```

Note that using `Exception` is too generic, you should more grain the type of exception you want to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
public static class Person{
    //other fields
    public String error = null;

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/testRest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person tst(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
        return ldapService.getUserByPrimaryKey("tst@ts.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setError("{\"ERROR\": " + e.getMessage() +"}");          
        return person;
    }
}
```

Sine you dont want to send back 500 dont do this:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
```

Also you cant cast string into Person class in java.

Comment: Thanks @tsolak Peteosian, that's mean that I have to add in each object a field error that will be set in the catch section

Comment: What you're suggesting would work, but the resulted JSON will look strange because `error` member will hold not an error string but a json with the error.

Comment: Just dont use curly brackets. It is just a matter of formatting the error.